# When i signin with an unknown email or wrong Password i'm still getting navigated and i also dont receive alerts

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

When i signin with an unknown email or wrong Password i'm still getting navigated and i dont receive alerts from the catch.

Code:

```
signin = (email, Password) => {
if(this.checkEmailString(email) && this.checkPasswordString(Password)){
  try 
  {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, Password)
    .catch(error => {   
      switch(error.code) {
        case 'There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.':
              alert('There is no user account with this email!')
              break;
        case 'The password is invalid or the user does not have a password.':
              alert('Wrong password!')
              break;
     }
   })
 }
 catch(err){
    alert("Error : ", err);
 }
}
else{
  alert('Please fix your email address and password');
}
   this.props.navigation.navigate('TempAfterLogin');
  };
```

Comment: Incorrectly tagged `java`, this is a Javascript question

Comment: But even if it isn't Java. The navigation happens after the if/else checks. Hence it always navigates as far as I can see

Answer (score 0):

This will always navigate because you are navigating it at the end of the condition block. Try this way

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("abc@gmail.com", "******")
   .then(function(firebaseUser) {
       // Success 
       this.props.navigation.navigate('TempAfterLogin');
   })
  .catch(function(error) {
       // Error Handling
  });
```

Comment: Maybe a dumb Question but this "firebaseUser". Is this an import package from firebase ? or just a variable like :     this.state = {
      email: " ",
      Password: " ",
    };

Comment: `firebaseUser` it's just a variable, you can use any variable like `user` `response` anything

Answer (score 0):

Your case strings are not Firebase Auth error codes.  They are diagnostic messages.  If you want to use actual error codes, you should consult the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword).

For example, maybe you want to use "auth/wrong-password" and "auth/user-not-found".